# How to have an animated gif during the page transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The project uses Backbone.js.

I tried doing it by appending a div with a gif to the html body.

```js
startLoadingAnimation = function() {
  $("<div id='loading'></div>").appendTo("body"); 
}
```

```css
#loading {
  display:    block;
  position:   fixed;
  z-index:    1000;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  height:     100%;
  width:      100%;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .8 ) 
    url('../img/loading.gif') 
    50% 50% 
    no-repeat;
}
```

It listens to an on-click event.

Everything goes as expected but the loading gif doesn't run the animation. I suspect it's because the browser is making a page request or something, so the gif doesn't run or stops running. Is there anyway around it, or a better way to put a "loading" animation in page transitions?

Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can't figure out wher is your issue, your snippet doesn't have any html and your javascript function doesn't launch on click in the snippet, but if i force a div with your css and a random gif, it works, can you try with an external link for the gif ? and do you see the frozen gif, or just the gray background ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using css animation instead of loading an external resource ?

You can find many css spinners around the web like this one :

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spinner-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 8px);
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  box-shadow: 20px 0px #FB404B, 0px 20px #FFA534, -20px 0px #87CB16, 0px -20px #1DC7EA;
  transform: translatez(0px);
  background: transparent;
  animation: spin 1.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 20px 0px #FB404B, 0px 20px #FFA534, -20px 0px #87CB16, 0px -20px #1DC7EA;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 40px 0px #FB404B, 0px 40px #FFA534, -40px 0px #87CB16, 0px -40px #1DC7EA;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner-container">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```